# What loopholes should be assumed when a name-specific file is used for code golf?

Tags: discussion, policy, code-golf

[I have posted this golfing tip for Bash before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237161/100411):

> In Pure Bash (or any other pure shellscript), use `.` for looping.

It's a tip that recomments using a file whose the program has. I have ever posted these answers that uses the tip:

- [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237156/100411)
- [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237157/100411)
- [Swap every two elements in a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237158/100411)
- [Tips for golfing in Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237161/100411)
- [Print 0 to 100 without 1-9 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237164/100411)
- [Uncomment a COBOL program!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237165/100411)

But I have thought that these situations can be thought:

- The program's file is placed on `/` (root directory), which prevents from using `cd /` to end the loop.
- The program's file is read-only, which prevents from using `>x` to end the loop.
- The program is invoked from different directory, such as invoked with `bash /path/to/x`, `bash ../../x`
- The program's directory has several files such as `bash`, `zsh`, `yes`, `rm -Rf /` that can have arbitrary data such as different shell script so invoking things such as `for x in *; do ...; done`, `*`, `eval *`, `. *` results in several behaviours.
- The shell script is invoked with the flag such as `-u` and `-e`.

What assumptions must be given for such programs?

Comment: It's worth noting that in bash/shell, you can work around this using `$0`, which contains the filename of the program.

Comment: But pathname and filename can have blank characters, so eventually `"$0"` is the safest as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, of course - too much Zsh (which doesn't have word splitting)